# Returning data from JavaScript file that contains AJAX function

Tags: javascript, ajax, function, dom, asynchronous

I have created the control.js file which contains AJAX functions that do POST and GET request to the server.

The problem is, I couldn't return the data I received from AJAX functions in control.js file to the other JavaScrip files.

I understand that we could not return the data from the Asynchronous functions directly.It requires additional function to handle the returned data from the function.

```
 function getServer(directory)
    {
        xmlHttp.open("GET",rootDirectory+directory);
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
            {
                if(xmlHttp.status == 200)
                {
                    Handler(xmlHttp.responseText);
                }
            }
        };
        xmlHttp.send();
    }
 function Handler(response)
 {
      return response;
 }
```

Function Handler returns the data correctly to every function calls within its own file (inside the control.js file).

Now, suppose if I have multiple JavaScript files, and I would like to call this function. How can I get the value that returns from the function in this file?

Example:

```
function construct()
{     
    // This function belongs to load.js file not control.js
    var handler = getServer("request/read.php?table=tasks");        
    console.log(handler);  // This one return nothing...//
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `Handler` function as an argument instead of hardcoding it into the function.

```
getServer("/foo/bar/", myFunction);
```